# How to get the module name in an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

In trapping an exception I have gotten the following `Exception`:

```
>>> exc_type
<class 'pymysql.err.ProgrammingError'>
```

Is there a simple way to get the value of `pymysql` so I can see which import/module it's coming from? Current I'm doing:

```
>>> exc_type.__module__.split('.')[0]
'pymysql'
```

But this seems a bit crude. What would be the best way to get that value?

Comment: `logger= logging.getLogger( __name__ )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`inspect.getmodule`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule):

```
>>> module = inspect.getmodule(exc_type)
>>> module
<module 'pymysql.err' from 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\pymysql\\err.py'>
>>> module.__name__
pymysql.err
>>> module.__package__
pymysql
```

Comment: Cool: `>>> inspect.getmodule(exc_type).__package__
'pymysql'`. It would be calling `__package__` and not `__module__`.

Comment: @FI-Info yes, after getting module object you can play around it and get `__name__`, `__package__` and other attributes.